# optimizing the query for joins

Tags: sql, left-join

I have below query -

```
select res.name, test.stringvalue 
from tr_resource res 
left outer join 
(select rch.resourceid,cv.stringvalue from tr_resourcecharac rch 
inner join tr_characvalue cv on rch.characvalueid = cv.characvalueid 
inner join tr_charac ch on cv.characid = ch.characid and ch.name='Security Clearance Required')test
on res.resourceid=test.resourceid
where res.resourceid=135021
```

I am getting below output for this -

```
name stringvalue
ABC  null
```

I dont want to use subquery after left join. Can you please let me know if there is a way to write this query as series of joins i tried writing below -

```
select res.name,cv.stringvalue 
from tr_resource res
left outer join tr_resourcecharac rch on res.resourceid=rch.resourceid
inner join tr_characvalue cv on rch.characvalueid =cv.characvalueid
inner join tr_charac ch on ch.characid=cv.characid and ch.name='Security Clearance Required'
where res.resourceid=135021
```

But this query is yielding no output.

For table scheme you may refer -

tr_resource as -

```
Resourceid  name
135021       ABC
```

tr_charac as

```
characid   name
1          Security Clearance Required
2          CH2
```

tr_characvalue as -

```
characvalueid characid stringvalue
cv1             1       XX
cv2             2       YY
cv3             2       zz
```

tr_resourcecharac as -

```
resourceid  characvalueid
135021          cv2
```

I already raised this question but nobody answered. So re-posting this question with more information

Comment: you post same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805712/left-outer-join-not-working !?

Comment: yes i tried to delete it but could not ...already raised to moderator for deleting the old post. i provided more information here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the query without the derived table as

```
SELECT res.name,
       cv.stringvalue
FROM   tr_resource res
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tr_resourcecharac rch
                       INNER JOIN tr_characvalue cv
                         ON rch.characvalueid = cv.characvalueid
                       INNER JOIN tr_charac ch
                         ON cv.characid = ch.characid
                            AND ch.name = 'Security Clearance Required'
         ON res.resourceid = test.resourceid
WHERE  res.resourceid = 135021
```

I doubt this will be an optimisation though. It is just an alternate way of expressing the same thing.

Or Another way would be

```
SELECT res.name,
       cv.stringvalue
FROM   tr_resourcecharac rch
       INNER JOIN tr_characvalue cv
         ON rch.characvalueid = cv.characvalueid
       INNER JOIN tr_charac ch
         ON cv.characid = ch.characid
            AND ch.name = 'Security Clearance Required'
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN tr_resource res
         ON res.resourceid = test.resourceid
WHERE  res.resourceid = 135021
```

Comment: thanks martin...i never knew that we could write on condition for left outer join as written by you....it worked perfectly

Comment: @anidesh - Also in this case as all of the other joins are `INNER JOINS` you could put them all first then `RIGHT JOIN` onto `tr_resource` at the end as an alternative.